# Trouble Implementing Webpack for a Large Project

Tags: django, webpack, ecmascript-6, frontend, large-files

I have been struggling trying to find the best way to implement webpack into the frontend workflow of a large existing Django project.

My two main concerns are:

1. The bundled file that webpack outputs pollutes the global namespace, possibly creating naming conflicts between existing client-side scripts.
2. The bundled file will be extremely large payload that would take too long to load.

Generally the project is broken into *apps*. It might make more sense to have a bundled file specific to each app.

Open to any other ideas. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is primarily a module loader. That means the sources it works with are expected to be modules that have an isolated scope, dependencies and exports. Unless you explicitly leak something by assigning it to the global scope or load sources that are have no support for modules, you shouldn't be worried about loaded scripts conflicting in the document. For example, if you would load a Webpack script to run in Django Admin, the jQuery version you'd see in your Webpack sources is the one you bundled with Webpack, not the one distributed with Django

Webpack offers an advanced [code-splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) technique during builds which will analyze the dependency graph of your modules and break your build into smaller chunks that can be asynchronously loaded on demand, so if your application is broken into *apps*, then you can have *per-app* sets of chunks that are only loaded when a user is on a certain app, advanced to a certain point.

Lastly, the bundled file you're seeing might be reduced in size if you use the provided [optimization options](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization) for production. I would also recommend you try `webpack@beta` now, with support for [tree-shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html) which will reduce the output bundle when you're using only portions of libraries that may have a large dependency graph.